# How to map equivalent AWG wire gauge to PCB trace width?

Tags: pcb-design, temperature, wire, trace

There are some online calculators that let you calculate trace width based on PCB trace characteristics e.g. this one from [digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-pcb-trace-width).

If there is a terminal connector on the PCB that connects solid AWG 18 wire to the PCB, what would be trace width that would result in similar characteristics in terms of temperature rise and resistance?

The AWG wire table shows ~6.5 ohm/1000’ and 2.32 A current carrying. If we use the digikey trace-width calc, a 18 AWG similar PCB trace would need to over 2" wide?

[image]

Comment: Please specify all the parameters you used in the calculator. I used 2.3A, 30deg ambient, 2oz copper, 1 inch long at a 10 deg rise and got ~0.5mm wide outer layer traces, and 1.25mm wide interior layer traces.

Comment: @Bryan added values.  However, asking for general case of mapping AWG wire to PCB trace.  I modified the temp rise to arrive at 6.9Ohm ~= 6.5 of the wire.

Comment: I see what's up, and you are correct - resistance is resistivity * cross sectional area so if you want 6.5 ohms/kft youll need to effectively hammer an 18AWG conductor to 0.00137" (1oz per sqft) so it's gonna be pretty wide. Generally traces are sized for a temperature rise or voltage drop and not a resistivity though, so you can get away with higher resistivity.